# Adding chart style

Tags: excel, bar-chart

I have a chart style that I am using a lot, stacked bar chart with the the first stack without fill. Currently I need to go to every portion of the first stack and set its fill property to "no fill".

How do I add a chart style which does not have a fill for the first stack or alternatively is there a way to automate the fill elimination from the chart?

[image: SO16983126 question example]

I would also add that the chart source is a pivot table (and not all chart types are supported with pivot tables).

Answer (score 0):

Select the chart, then PivotChart Tools > Format > Current Selection - Series1 (or to suit), Shape Styles – Shape Fill and No Fill should achieve no fill for that entire series. It is quite fiddly but reliable. The alternative is to click one of the bars to be hidden and with luck the set will be selected automatically (if not, try again!)